# how to get coordinates only in specific column in a picture of a grid

Tags: jquery

is it possible to get cordinates from a specific column from a picture 
like it will say when i hover over column 1 it will give me it like column 1 cordinate 1,1 and then i hover over column 2 it will give me it like column 2 cordinate 1,1

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span id="image_coords_click"></span><span id="image_coords_now"> </span></div>
<img id="image" class="aligncenter" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-c0lydOomMh8/UdMXTLn0frI/AAAAAAAAKdU/xa8kZMf23uQ/s721/100+number+grid.png" width="1475" height="1475" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#image').mousemove( function(event) {
 window.current_x = Math.round(event.pageX - $('#image').offset().left);
 window.current_y = Math.round(event.pageY - $('#image').offset().top);
 window.current_coords = window.current_x + ', ' + window.current_y;
 $('#image_coords_now').html('Column: ' + window.current_coords + '.');
  }).mouseleave( function() {
 $('#image_coords_now').html('&nbsp;');
  }).click( function() {
 $('#image_coords_click').html('Last click: ' + window.current_coords + '. ');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I have an idea how to do it, I'm trying to create an example

Comment: I modified my answer, I hope it will be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try watching this:[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/ee8e6uxy/3/)

```
function column(){
  var cell1={x0:21,y0:25,x1:163,y1:165};
var x=$('#x').html();
var y=$('#y').html();
/*
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
  console.log(cell1['x0']);
  console.log(cell1['x1']);
  console.log(cell1['y0']);
  console.log(cell1['y1']);
*/
if (x>=cell1['x0'] && x<=cell1['x1'] && y>=cell1['y0'] && y<=cell1['y1'])
{
console.log('cell oone');
}
else {
console.log('other cell');

}
```

my idea is:

- I defined cell1, of coordinates '{x0: 21, y0: 25, x1: 163, y1: 165};'
- I took the coordinates at the time of click
- pressing the button, check if the coordinates are inside the cell1 defined by me

  1. go to cell one
  2. click with the mouse
  3. Press the button
  4. look at the console

I thought it only on a cell, it would eventually be applied to the remaining cells, but it's a big job

**NEW CODE:**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/mjommsbw/8/)

1. click on the cell you want